Get option text value of all dropdowns in Angular reactive form
After a lot of search, and after trying Copilot, didn't found the answer.
I have a dynamic reactive form with 1 to n dropdowns.
When changing any dropdown, I need to loop all existing dropdowns and get the text value (not the value), to verify some rules.
The data structure is like:
[
{
   id: 1,
   options: [
     {
       key: 100,
       value: "First"
     },
     {
       key: 101,
       value: "Second"
     },
     {
       key: 102,
       value: "Third"
     }
   ]
},
{
   id: 2,
   options: [
     {
       key: 100,
       value: "First"
     },
     {
       key: 101,
       value: "Second"
     },
     {
       key: 102,
       value: "Third"
     }
   ]
},...
]

I build the form this way:
form!: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    const group: any = {};

    this.myArrayOfDataObjects.forEach(data => {
      group[data.id] = new FormControl('');
    });

    this.form = new FormGroup(group);
}

HTML (the dropdown part):
@for (data of myArrayOfDataObjects; track data.id) {
    <mat-select
      [id]="data.id"
      [formControlName]="data.id"
      (selectionChange)="changeValue($event)"
    >
      <mat-option>--</mat-option>
      @for (opt of vs.options; track opt.key) {
        <mat-option [value]="opt.key">{{ opt.value }}</mat-option>
      }
    </mat-select>
}

And, when changing any value, I know I can loop it all values:
changeValue() {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.form.value)) {
        console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
        // Also
        console.log(this.form.get(key)?.value);
    }
}

But don't know how to get the text value. Any ideas?
Stackblitz example here

Add on mat-option  [attr.data-myoption]="opt.value" and read it  like this:  onSelectionChange(event: MatSelectChange) {
const selectedOption = event.source.selected as MatOption;
const customAttribute = selectedOption._getHostElement().getAttribute('data-myoption');}

You can do that thing in an easy way, but this don't solve the original problem: you are reading the text on every change of one dropdown, and I need to read ALL dropdowns texts on every change on any of them

We can use this.form.value to access the values! I also use <form [formGroup]="form">...</form> to define the form on which the elements belong to, and a button to fetch the values!
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

/**
 * @title Basic select
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    @for (data of myArrayOfDataObjects; track data.id) {
      <mat-select
        [id]="data.id.toString()"
        [formControlName]="data.id"
        (selectionChange)="changeValue($event)"
      >
        <mat-option>--</mat-option>
        @for (opt of data.options; track opt.key) {
          <mat-option [value]="opt.key">{{ opt.value }}</mat-option>
        }
      </mat-select>
    }
  </form>
<br/>
  <button (click)="getValue()">Click to get the values</button>
<br/>

  {{form.value | json}}
  `,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  myArrayOfDataObjects = [
    {
      id: 1,
      options: [
        {
          key: 100,
          value: 'First',
        },
        {
          key: 101,
          value: 'Second',
        },
        {
          key: 102,
          value: 'Third',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      options: [
        {
          key: 104,
          value: 'First',
        },
        {
          key: 105,
          value: 'Second',
        },
        {
          key: 106,
          value: 'Third',
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  form!: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    const group: any = {};

    this.myArrayOfDataObjects.forEach((data) => {
      group[data.id] = new FormControl('');
    });

    this.form = new FormGroup(group);
  }

  changeValue(event: any) {
    Object.entries(this.form.value).forEach(
      ([key, value]: any, index: number) => {
        console.log(`${key}: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
        // Also
        const dValue = this.form.get(key)?.value;
        const finalValue = this.myArrayOfDataObjects?.[index]?.options?.find(
          (x: any) => x.key === value
        )?.value;
        console.log('only value:', finalValue);
      }
    );
  }

  getValue() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

The idea is good, but it changes the real value of the dropdown. I need that values stay the same and just, be able to read the text

Interesting, but not working when option data is not the same always. Change id:2 indexes to 104, 105 and 106, and will not work

Thank you @Narem, after your second try I was exploring the same final solution, using the original data array to search on it. That way, it is working. I'm not convinced to be a perfect solution, but I don't see any other response, due to lack of form controls to access text values. Maybe someone will find a more straight solution later.

@Eagle Do consider my first solution using the data object directly! its a good one also, nice question!
